# How to set all the images that uploaded on the Blog to a default size automatically

Tags: html, css, image, set, size

I am using Blogger and I want to upload images and be set to a default size that I will choose, automatically. The Blogger offers small, medium, large extra large in order to choose as soon as you add an image but I want this to be done automatically to the size that I want, because I want to upload 400+ images so doing this seperately for each image is really hard for me right now. Please could you tell me if I can use HTML code or CSS in order to customize the size of the images that I upload?

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use photoshop or something like it. 
Within photoshop you have to choose IMAGE-SIZE and set it there (after you've uploaded all the images). So you do it once and all images are set to this size automatically. After that just save them on your pc and use them.

As for using html and css:
e.g. you're using `<img>`  and you've set all images like this:

```
img{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}
```

Will make it look messy. Because if you have images that are bigger than 500px in width or height, they will be cut! I don't think you want that.

So it's strongly advised to pre-set the height and width of the image BEFORE you upload it for your page. And a program like photoshop does the job nicely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your advise, the problem is after I upload them and then add them the default size is medium( it re- adjusts automatically from the original size) and the preffered size that I want would be x-large, but it's hard enough to change all of them manually. The html code that you refer to, I should use it on the post(HTML tab)? not by going to CSS settings?

Comment: Yes for example in your html you could put something like:
`<img src="images/1.png" alt="picture">`

And you css would like like:  `img{
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}`

If this helps, don't hold back to give the credit for it :)